# Any Node.js HTTP request module that works both in the server and in the browser when bundled with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, xmlhttprequest, webpack

I need a request module that works both in the Node.js server and in the client, when bundled with Webpack.

My requirements are really basic. I just need to do some HTTP Ajax requests, like `get` and `post`. Automatic JSON parsing would be awesome.

I'm taking a look at [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), which seems solid by the number of commits and downloads, but the website doesn't mention whether it works while bundled in the browser.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try request, and get back to us. Should be fine.

Comment: I tried request, didn't work for me. Needed lots of other dependencies. Maybe I'm doing something wrong though. Did you get it working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

Features

- Make XMLHttpRequests from the browser
- Make http requests from node.js
- Supports the Promise API
- Intercept request and response
- Transform request and response data
- Cancel requests
- Automatic transforms for JSON data
- Client side support for protecting against XSRF

Comment: You have revived this question and, as it turns out, axios is what I've bee using for years now. Totally recommended.

Comment: I hope you get a badge for having your answer accepted after 1 year lol

Comment: You did but not a very interesting one :)

Comment: Actually i was looking for alternatives to axios and stumbled about this question. I still prefere axios over superagent because for my usecase I need the possibility to modify request bodies and could not find that in superagent.Thx for the badge :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try [SuperAgent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

> SuperAgent is a small progressive **client-side HTTP** request library,
>   **and Node.js module** with the same API

> Works with browserify and **should work with webpack**